# C# Application prompts for Admin Credentials for particular user

Tags: windows-7, administrator, uac, c#

I have two users one a month old, and one brand new.

Both are standard users(belong to standard users group).

UAC Setting is set to Default.

Problem is while launching a C# App, old_user prompts for admin previlage, while the new user doesn't.

Why?

Comment: Welcome. Make sure your running the **exact** program on both users.

Comment: Where is the application installed? Is it installed using Click Once?

Comment: @Diago: its installed in Program Files

Comment: @Wizlog: Thanks .... Yes I am sure that I am running same program in both users

Comment: Whats this app doing?  Why dose it require admin rights?  and did the old user always need admin rights to access it?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is, if you understand UAC well, to fire up Process Monitor from Sysinternals and attach it to the program at launch.

Another way is to download Microsoft's Appcompat toolkit. It contains a tool called the Standard user analyzer. It essentially is test trial that breaks the program as soon as it hits a UAC prompt.  Plus it tells you why!!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756983.aspx

> To identify application compatibility problems for pre-Windows Vista
>   applications
>
> Log on to a Windows Vista computer as an administrator in Admin
>   Approval Mode.
>
> Click Start, click All Programs, and then click Standard User
>   Analyzer.
>
> In the Standard User Analyzer, for Target Application, specify the
>   full directory path for an application to test or click the Browse
>   button to locate the program's executable file with Windows Explorer.
>
> Click Launch and then click Continue at the User Account Control
>   dialog box.
>
> After the test application launches, perform standard administrative
>   tasks in the application, and close the application when you have
>   completed.
>
> In the Standard User Analyzer, examine the output on each tab. Use
>   this data to identify the compatibility issues that the program might
>   have.